# Php a line need to underseand

Tags: php

what is the meaning of this line? Can any body help me? I have confusion on last 2 sign `:''`
why without this two sign browser make error? Thanks all.

```
isset($_POST['but'])? $_POST['but']:'';
```

Comment: Check out the ternary operator: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: it seems, it means if $_POST['but'] contains value leave as it is else set '' (empty string) in it.

Comment: @Adil: no, it wouldn't change/add the value if it does not exist. It is not shown what is done with the result of the conditional operator.

Comment: yup, @FelixKling you caaught it right,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just another way to write if/else statement.
For example:

```
$but = isset($_POST['but'])? $_POST['but']:'';
```

Would be the same as:

```
if(isset($_POST['but'])){
$but= $_POST['but'];
}else{
$but = '';
}
```

Comment: Thank you meda.I have understand by you post.

Answer (score 1):

U use the tenary comparison operator

A ternary operator have value for true and false

```
($contidition) ? true : false;
```

Please refer php documentation about ternary operator [comparison operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

In case of:

```
isset( $_POST['but'] ) ? $_POST['but'] : ''
```

What it mean is, when `$_POST['but']` exist, use it, otherwise use empty string

If u use php version > 5.3 u can use something like

```
isset($_POST['but']) ? : ''
```

Answer (score 0):

If [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.post.php) request body contains `but` parameter - use it, overwise use empty string.

If you are misunderstood `statement ? something : anything` code - it's the [Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing but the `Ternary Operator`

**Explanation:**
If your `$_POST['but']` is set , then it will assign the same value to it , else it will set a `''`

A clear example [`here`](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/3/12/4)

Answer (score 0):

Well it's called an `ternary` operator.

**Example**:

```
$value = 5;
($value > 2) ? true : false; // returns true
```

The expression (expr1) ? (expr2) : (expr3) evaluates to expr2 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 if expr1 evaluates to FALSE.

```
(isset($_POST['but'])) ? $_POST['but']:'';
```

Here if your value `$_POST['but']` is set then it will return `$_POST['but']` else it will return ''.